# How can I read each line of a text file (contains unique id) in bash using for loop, save it into a variable and use it subsequently for

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Hi I am new to bash scripting, trying to read a text file that contains my ids and want to use it in a loop by saving it to a `$variable` and using that for fetching some data.

```
#!/bin/bash

file = "Cell_ids.text"
i=1

for i in file; do

        i=$((i+1))  
         **id** = **$i**




sbatch --mem=4G --time=100 -o fetch_data.%j.out -e fetch_data.%j.err -J fetch_data  <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /docs/some-tools.jar --library ${**id**}
EOF
```

Comment: Note that using `for i in $(cat file)` is a bad idea: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a variable, you aren't allowed to have spaces around the `=` sign, so your `file` variable isn't getting set. You also need to prefix it with a `$` sign when you want to iterate through it.

Your `for` loop is also never closed, to signify the end of your loop, use the keyword `done`. I'm not sure what you want `**id** = **$i**` to do, but I'm guessing you want your script to look more like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file="Cell_ids.text"

for i in $(cat $file); do
    sbatch \
        --mem=4G \
        --time=100 \
        -o fetch_data.%j.out \
        -e fetch_data.%j.err \
        -J fetch_data << EOF
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /docs/some-tools.jar --library $i
EOF
done
```

I removed the `i=1` because it doesn't need to be declared before the loop since it will get set automatically. I'm not familiar with `sbatch`, but if you have an issue with that command, you may want to post a new question specifically about that.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29. `while IFS= read -r i; do ...; done < "$i"` is the better approach.

Comment: @terdon true, I made an assumption about the ids being alphanumeric and whitespace delimited. if I knew that was correct, does using some form of `read` still provide additional safety?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for more details than you ever wanted to know! Yes, in this case it will probably be OK but it's a bad habit to get into since `while` will always work and this will often fail. So just always use `while`.